# How to make program run different things every second time?

Tags: c, linux, variables

I have a C script, I need to make it work as a lever, ie each time transfer my Linux from one state to another.

I need something like this:

```
if (even_execution) {state = 0;} 
else {state = 1;}
```

Perhaps I should write `even_execution` variable to a file or add an environment variable?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by transfer my Linux from one state to another?

Comment: Yes, write it to a file.

Comment: It doesn't matter. It just has to rotate 2 different things every time.

Comment: Are you going to modify "even_execution" frequently?

Comment: Not very. About 1-2 times a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're scripting, I suggest you use a scripting language for it. Such as:

```
#!/bin/bash

STATE=$(cat .state)
STATE=${STATE:-1}
if ((STATE)); then
    echo ohyeah
else
    echo ohno
fi
echo -n $((1-STATE)) > .state
```

**Edit:** regarding where to put the file, perhaps `/var/lock/`, `/var/tmp/` or `/var/local/` might be suitable (at least on Debian). If you want to "modify it" every shutdown, I suggest you simply

```
rm /var/lock/strange_state
```

at termination.

Comment: This is a good example with writing variable to a file. But isn't environment variable better?

Comment: @Anarchy_asker [no, because it wouldn't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372627/is-it-possible-to-pass-environment-variables-from-child-to-parent-in-user-space).

Comment: The most hard question is where it's best to put the file so that it does not interfere, and how to modify it at every shutdown.